# How can I take multiple occurrences of 5 out of a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, operators

None the less, this is the code for the function that should take out all instances of 5, but I get an error:

```
i = [ 6 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 5 ]

def removeFive ( i ) :
    x = 0
    amount = len ( i )
    for x in range ( amount - 1 ) :
        if i [ x ] == 5 :
            i . remove ( [ x ] )
        else:
            pass
        x = x + 1
    print ( i )
    return None

removeFive ( i )
```

error message :

```
i . remove ( [ x ] )
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

any help?

Comment: I don't know python at all, but maybe you should remove i[x]?

Comment: You're right, thanks dude, derp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.remove()` function actually accepts the element to remove, in this case `5` , and not the index (especially not the index as a list). That is why you are getting the error. Example of this behavior -

```
>>> l = [5,4,3,2,1]
>>> l.remove(1)
>>> l
[5, 4, 3, 2]   #note that element 3 got removed not the index 3.
```

Also , you should not remove elements from a list while iterating over it , since the first time you change the list, the indexes for the elements also change (due to the removal) and hence you miss checking some elements.

The easiest way for you to do this would be to return a new list that does not have the element you want to remove, and assign that back to i, Example -

```
def removeFive ( i ) :
    return [x for x in i if x != 5]
i = removeFive(i)
i
>>> [6, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

You do not even need a function -

```
i = [x for x in i if x != 5]
i
>>> [6, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to *take out all instances of 5* this is one way to do it:

```
>>> i = [ 6 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 5 ]
>>> x = [e for e in i if e != 5]
>>> x
[6, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use built-in method [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter) , this way:

```
>>> i = [ 6 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 5 ]
>>> filter(lambda x: x!=5, i)
[6, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Did you profile it against the list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

The `list.remove` method accept the value not its index so first of all you need to pass a value to remove, also you have passed the index in a list, seems that you want to pass `i[x]`.

But as a more pythonic way you can use a list comprehension to remove the 5's :

```
>>> i = [ 6 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 5 ]
>>> [t for t in i if t!=5]
[6, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```